# Integration using Parseval's theorem

Tags: integration, parsevals-identity

Would it be possible, to have some guidance to compute the following, using Parseval's theorem for any integer N≥1.

[image: integration using Parseval's theorem]
Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing an $x$ in the numerator?

Comment: Use the fact that $$\frac{\sin{\left ( N+\frac12 \right )x}}{\sin{(x/2)}} = 1+ 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \cos{k x} $$ and orthogonality over the integration interval to derive the value.  The answer is $2 (2N+1) \pi$.

Comment: Thank you I can see how to continue now !